# PIL merge of two images with alpha channels - not working as expected

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

There's a bunch of questions here on SO which provide answers to the present question, however the output is not the expected.

The goal is to merge two RGBA images. The information on the alpha channel of each image is not the same.

The current (simplified) code is:

```
from PIL import Image

image = '1.png'
watermark = '2.png'

wmark = Image.open(watermark)
img = Image.open(image)

img.paste(wmark, (0, 0), wmark)
img.save("result.png", "PNG")
```

The two images are:

Background

[image: Background]

Foreground

[image: Foreground]

Expected output

[image: Expected output]

Actual result

[image: Actual result]

In case you don't see the difference, here are the alpha channels (inverted for better visualization) of the final versions.

Expected result - alpha channel

[image: Expected result - alpha channel]

Actual result - alpha channel

[image: Actual result - alpha channel]

So with that said, is there any way of doing this or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT - clarification following @zenpoy comment:

If the foreground image has a certain amount of opacity, I want that to be taken into account when superimposing both images, but I don't want the alpha channel of the second image to be added to the first. Much like putting a piece of glass (the foreground image) in front of a paper image (background).

In other words, if the background image was RGB instead of RGBA, the final image should have no alpha information.

Comment: can you provide a mathematical explanation of what you are trying to achieve? what do you expect in each pixel's value in each channel?

Comment: I'm continually disappointed at PIL's inability to properly handle alpha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your initial description, the following idea seems to be equivalent. Let X, Y be two RGBA images.  Merge X and Y considering the bands RGB from X and the bands RGBA from Y, producing an image Z. Set the band A in Z to that of the band A in X. This contradicts your final statement, but it seems to give the expected output in this situation.

So, this is the code:

```
image = '1.png'
watermark = '2.png'

wmark = Image.open(watermark)
img = Image.open(image)

ia, wa = None, None
if len(img.getbands()) == 4:
    ir, ig, ib, ia = img.split()
    img = Image.merge('RGB', (ir, ig, ib))
if len(wmark.getbands()) == 4:
    wa = wmark.split()[-1]

img.paste(wmark, (0, 0), wmark)
if ia:
    if wa:
        # XXX This seems to solve the contradiction, discard if unwanted.
        ia = max_alpha(wa, ia)
    img.putalpha(ia)

img.save('result.png')
```

where the function `max_alpha` is:

```
def max_alpha(a, b):
    # Assumption: 'a' and 'b' are of same size
    im_a = a.load()
    im_b = b.load()
    width, height = a.size

    alpha = Image.new('L', (width, height))
    im = alpha.load()
    for x in xrange(width):
        for y in xrange(height):
            im[x, y] = max(im_a[x, y], im_b[x, y])
    return alpha
```

This new function seems to take into consideration the contradiction mentioned.

Comment: Which version of PIL are you using? I have 1.1.7 here. At least with the images provided in this example, your code is failing on `img.split()` with an internal PIL error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bands'` on `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1497`

Comment: I have 1.1.7 too, and that is a bit strange. Try adding `img.load()` after the line `img = Image.open(image)`.

Comment: Just a small note, if the image doesn't have an alpha channel the code will fail on the `img.split()` line. An alternative may be `channels = img.split()`, `img = Image.merge('RGB', channels[:3])` and `if len(channels) == 4: img.putalpha(channel[3])`. PS: Thanks, the output is still not quite the expected but is close enough (better actually). On the expected result, the intersection of the crosses has a weaker alpha as if opacity was subtracted to it. Your suggestion keeps alpha untouched in that region.

Comment: Fine, I've updated the example so it is a little more robust. I added a new function `max_alpha` which seems to be what you want, could you check it ? Thanks.