# Blending Images while maintaining opacity

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have been trying to blend together images (using PIL in python) to form one combined image. However, for both of the images to blend in properly, I've been keeping the alpha as 0.5. This leads to the image being translucent and losing its opacity. Is there anyway I can blend the 2 images without losing its opacity.
The Code:

```
import Image
a = Image.open("image1.png")
b = Image.open("image2.png")
c = Image.blend(a,b,0.5)
c.save("abc.png", "PNG")
```

These are the images: (I'm a new user and am not allowed to post images or more than 2 hyperlinks. Hence, I'm putting links.)

image1 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/EphiR.png

abc - https://i.stack.imgur.com/useql.png

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750447/pil-merge-of-two-images-with-alpha-channels-not-working-as-expected do what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty version that can be improved on.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops
from PIL import ImageOps
import numpy as np

a = Image.open("a.png")
b = Image.open("b.png")

# Finds the difference between the two images. Then inverts so differences are black.
diff = ImageOps.invert(ImageChops.difference(a, b)) 
# Then we use numpy to convert black to red. 
image = diff.convert('RGBA')
data = np.array(image)

r1,g1,b1 = 0,0,0
r2,g2,b2 = 255,0,0

red, green, blue = data[:,:,0], data[:,:,1], data[:,:,2]
mask = (red == r1) & (green == g1) & (blue == b1)
data[:,:,:3][mask] = [r2, g2, b2]
# Then we convert the array back to an image.
overlay = Image.fromarray(data)
# And blend with the original. 
imgblend = ImageChops.add(a.convert('RGBA'), overlay,2)
imgblend.show()
```