# PIL paste image with alpha appears faded

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am working with multiple images that I would like to stack on top of each other to create a single image. However, in working with them, I'm noticing that if the image already has transparency (alpha != 255), that part of the image appears faded. If there is no transparency, all is good.

I saved one of the images I was working with to a PNG and created a small bit of code that duplicates the problem. Essentially, I'm creating a new image with a transparent background and then pasting the image on top:

```
from PIL import Image

img=Image.new('RGBA', (946,627), (0,0,0,0))
overlayImage = Image.open('drawing.png')
img.paste(overlayImage, (0,0), overlayImage)
img.save('drawing-pasted.png')
```

When this completes, drawing-pasted.png looks like this:

[image: drawing-pasted.png]

But the original drawing (drawing.png) looked like this:

[image: drawing.png]

(Images cropped manually to show detail.) The original image circles fill color has an alpha value of 179.

Has anyone else encountered this, and what am I doing wrong?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

```
image = Image.open(file_path)
img1 = Image.open(file_path)
cords = (233.22)
image.paste(img1, cords, mask=img1)
image.save(path_where_you_want_to_save_final_image)
```

simply use this block of code

Answer (score 0):

The background you are creating is black and fully transparent the original is blue but with an alpha of 179 so you have 2 pixels (0,0,0,0) and (0,0,255,179) *assuming 100% blue* - since you are pasting the image in it will be **over** the background so will use the alpha of the new image allowing (255-179)/255 or about 30% black.  *(N.B. The alpha of the background makes no difference since it is behind the new image)*

You could use `overlayImage.putalpha` to set the alpha to 255 start from your image rather than a black background.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean here. If I put an alpha of 255 on the image, I get the blue dots, but with a full black background, which isn't what I want. I used the transparent image because this is the smallest amount of code that replicates the problem. My main goal is to start with an image (a map) and overlay these points on it without changing their level of transparency. But right now, the dot image fades.

Comment: Ah! so your current background is a map and the overlay is black with blue dots, in that has you need to have an overlay with an alpha of 0 i.e. a colour of (0,0,0,0) except where the dots should be where __just the dots are__ i.e. they should have a colour of (0, 0, 255. 255).  You can do this with mask generation or, since you are probably generating your dots from your code by setting their colour and alpha.

Comment: Well, the dots are (0, 0, 255, 179) with the rest of the image being a transparent background. So, I have that image (which is the second image above), but when I paste it on top of my map image (using the dot image as the mask), the alpha on the dots "fades".

Comment: As I said above if you don't wish the dots to "fade" you need them to be opaque on a transparent layer otherwise they will drop in intensity as the background shows through.

Comment: So, if I understand what you're saying, I should be painting the circles on another layer fully opaque (alpha = 255) and then setting that layer's overall alpha to 179? The issue with that, is that even in this example, the fill color has an alpha of 179, but the line color has an alpha higher than that, for emphasis. Other images may have varying degrees of alpha per point. By altering the individual alphas and setting the layer alpha, I would lose these differences, correct?

Comment: I'm finding that the code suggested in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750447/pil-merge-of-two-images-with-alpha-channels-not-working-as-expected does the trick. Still trying to fully understand what is happening, but this gets the result I'm looking for.

Comment: No I am saying that the overlay layer should be full transparent except where the dots are where it should be fully opaque.  Glad you have found something that works for you.